# Turning polymorphic table association into a type column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Say I have an `entities` table (200mil rows +) in which each row has a `contentId` column that references a piece of content that exists in either a `posts`, `comments` and `replies` table (without FK's).

Now, for each row in `entities` I'd like to check which table the associated piece of content exists in, and return that as the type.

This is part of a data migration process. Any ideas on how to perform this in a relatively performant way?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a mapping table and then use it in your migration, something based on the following query. It might be costly, but you should only have to run it once. If your entity data set is *live*, then you can add triggers to automatically maintain the *entities_type* association table for you.

Depending on the next steps, it might be way smarter to maintain three different tables rather than a *tag* table like this. I hope it gets you started, tho.

```
create table entities_type as

select 'post', contentId
  from entities
  join posts using(contentId)

union all

select 'comments', contentId
  from entities
  join comments using(contentId)

union all

select 'replies', contentId
  from entities
  join replies using(contentId)
;
```